# crystal report page footer print on bottom of page

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have Page Footer()PF A and B, whenever I suppress PFa, PFb will move up following the report footer.
Imagine the vertical lines as the line number,

```
|Page Header
|Details
|Report Footer
|Page Footer A
|Page Footer B
```

The PFa shows only in the last page, using the formula in the suppress section:

```
pagenumber <> totalpagecount
```

This is the result

```
Page 1           Page 2
|Page Header     |Page Header
|Details         |Details
|Report Footer   |Report Footer
|Page Footer B   |Page Footer A
|                |Page Footer B
```

Now I want the report to be like this

```
Page 1           Page 2
|Page Header     |Page Header
|Details         |Details
|Report Footer   |Report Footer
|                |Page Footer A
|Page Footer B   |Page Footer B
```

Answer (score 7):

In Section Expert there is an option "Print at Bottom of Page", use that to keep it at the bottom.  This is often used for building invoices or bills to keep the total at the bottom.

Comment: I think the point is that when you have multiple sections in your page footer (or in any section for that matter), the "Print at Bottom of Page" option is greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple Page Footers and you suppress them by various rules, the problem in crystal is that Page Footer A does not stick to bottom, but it is occupying the place on top of Page Footer B even if B is suppressed. To fix check "Underlay Following Sections". That fixed the problem for me

Comment: Just adding further notes here. The point is PF prints at bottom of page.  Once you start spitting up PF you can not have multiple PF printing at the same time and still have the 'print at utmost bottom of page' functionality.  Would be nice to be able to have  PFa PFb PFz where PFz section works as the 'utmost bottom of page' section with PFn stacking on top.  My work around for this is as mentioned by everyone is to have PFa and PFb etc with 'PFz' contents added to both at the very bottom.  As also noted all PFn sections need to be the same height for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it moved down but not at the bottom of the page you could add another section (eg PFc), then move the contents of PFb into PFc and add a formula to invert the suppression of PFa:

```
pagenumber = totalpagecount
```

Then just make PFb the same dimensions of PFa.

Answer (score 0):

In the left margin,. right-click the Report Footer and go to Section expert.  Put a check box in the option for Print at Bottom of Page.  This should do it for you.

The report footer doesn't get handled like the Page Footer does.  This option will tell the report to print it at the bottom of the page for you.

Comment: The OP is talking about PF not RF; hence the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I little late, but on my reports, I have 2 headers and 4 footers that vary depending on which organization within our company is printing the report.

After 2, the space after the footer got extremely bad, I found I needed to add "underlay following sections" to get them to print at the bottom of the page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use option in Section Expert / Page footer : Reserve Minimum Page Footer,
that will print the footer at bottom of the page, just make sure each footer has the same height (is somehow reserved for the biggest?)